# What could you scavenge from the average American house?

Tags: post-apocalypse

There was a nuclear war about ten years ago. Now, people are coming back and stripping InsertCityHere of useful supplies.

I want to know what they could get from the average American suburban house.

They're mostly looking for things useful in car maintenance, defences, and weapon/armour construction. Let's say they cannot scavenge food and water as it's no good, but anything else is okay.

For reference, the society is mostly small groups of scavengers and farmers. Things are pretty disorganized, and there are no real towns or cities. Most people keep to themselves, and there is very little trade.

Comment: If the fallout series is anything to go by, a bunch of ammunition, bottle caps and some lock picks. I don't want to sound evil, but the simple answer would be everything that they left in the house. Clothes, pots and pans, jewelry, toys, computers/laptops, furniture, tv, fridge, washing machine, dryer, dish washer, dishes. Is there any reason you haven't searched for common household items and appliances?

Comment: i'm trying to get some of the things that i wouldn't think of, and things that google won't either

Comment: What can't you scavenge from a modern American house? Listing everything in my house would take a book; so I think this is too broad.

Comment: Question is a little broad: can you narrow down some pertinent facts, please? What is it you actually want to do? What kind of "civilisation" is left? How long after the war?

Comment: i'll edit it to specify that i'm looking for things that really stand out

Comment: Please define "really stand out". And in what context. I mean: Mom's collection of early 20th century garden Gnomes "really stands out"...but how useful would that lot be power nuclear war? The edit is still far, far too broad!

Comment: I just edited it to say "or things that you think could be rather useful to the scavengers"

Comment: What we're getting at is that, literally, ANYTHING, in a house can be "useful". That's why it's your job to narrow your question down, so it won't be closed as too broad!

Comment: This is your question and your scenario! Make up a time frame! This is importan, because some things can last a long time, others expire quickly.

Comment: edited again, and i will do some skim research to try and figure out the time frame

Comment: What kind of society do the scavengers have? Are they basically agrarian, looking for things that will let them hunt, fight, and farm? Or is there a technological society somewhere that they're hoping to sell scrap to? Do they work copper, iron, steel? Can they render plastics? There's a lot in a house that could be critical or worthless depending on the scavengers.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to VTC! Please take some time to think about your scenario and write up a good question!

Comment: rewrote question, i hope that it's clearer now

Comment: the entire world was hit by the nukes and over 80% of people died, so there's a lot of missing information and distrustful people. the scavengers are scavenging so they can find items that they can't make themselves. they are not trading. though society is disorganized, there are still small communities (2-10 people) and so farmers give their surplus to neighbors or store it for later. very few people don't farm, and those are the ones who take instead of make. @user535733

Comment: Well, the question was always clear! It's clear like bright Kansas sky --- wide open and broad as the world! And that's the issue: your question is *too broad*. Every answer you get is just going to be a variation on "everything". Every answer will be pure opinion.

Comment: What could you find?  Anything in a Walmart, a hardware store, a clothing store, a liquor store, your local Adam & Eve.... But this depends on what you mean by "average."  There will be massive variation based on economy, base industry of the region, interests of the homeowner, age and quantity of children... "average" is indeed too broad.  But more to the point, why scavange house-to-house when hitting one Walmart would be the same as a thousand houses?  What you really want is the Walmart distribution hubs.  Jackpot!

Answer (score 6):

**Start with the bones of the house...**
Take the pipes and wires out of the walls, the sheet metal from the air ducts, some of the wall studs and solid wood doors.  If the house has a metal roof, take it as long flat sheets of metal can be very useful for rainwater harvesting.  Same for closet shelving, gutters and window panes.

**Next, look at the appliances...**
More sheet metal from the covers, motors and heating elements from inside.  The water heater is worth taking intact as it can server as a water container.  Magnets from the microwaves. There is probably a barbecue grill and maybe a generator in the garage.  Don't overlook the ceiling fans, lamps (with light bulbs) and extension cords.

**Chemicals!**
Soap is always welcome, but bleach and ammonia are potential weapons.  Bug spray can be used like mace.  Raid the liquor cabinet, medicine cabinet and any cigarette stashes for trading supplies.  Check the garage and shed for fertilizer and if there is a pool, find the chlorine tablets.

**Firearms**
This is America after all!  Butcher knives, lighters, carpentry and gardening tools can also make effective weapons.  Don't rule out the possibility of finding decorative swords, bows and crossbows.  Keep your eyes out for ammo, bolts and arrows.  Look in the cars for snow chains, tow chains and gasoline.

**Sundries**
Warm Clothing, blankets, towels and sheets (for bandages), first aid supplies, paper, pens, scissors, cutlery, cooking pans, toilet paper, toothbrushes, deodorant, mirrors (for signalling), batteries, vitamins.

**Obscure but Possible**
Check the back yard for fruit trees and berry bushes. mason jars and canning supplies, free weights and portable exercise equipment, scuba equipment, camping supplies.

Comment: Imagine an open world game where you could loot everything like you described....there wouldn't be any houses left.

Comment: I had a lot of fun writing this answer... just walking around my house looking for hidden treasures.  Could have gone on all night\

Comment: Forget the decorative swords. They're worthless in anything like a fight. Unless, of course, you've got a real sword (or just about anything else) and your oppo thinks he's cool with his decorative Conan sword!

Comment: I'm not so sure about decorative swords being useless.  Yes, they are garbage metal and are initially dull, but they can be sharpened pretty easily and although the edge won't last long with regular use, they would be devastating immediately after sharpening.  The power of a long sword's reach shouldn't be underestimated.

Comment: Start with the bones of the house - in medievel times for example raiders took the metal clips, holding the city wall together, or even the very stones of old castles